# Transitioning from Visual Studio 2010 to Visual Studio (community) 2015

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio

I want upgrade a machine<sup>1</sup> currently running Visual Studio 2010, mainly for C++ to Visual Studio 2015<sup>2</sup>, that will be using mainly C++ and C#.

Could someone help me to do it as painlessly as possible?

My main concerns are related to the procedure that I need to follow, for example:
do I need to firstly uninstall the current version, delete remaining folders, clean registers? Are the projects, solutions and code valid or is any conversion needed?

---

1. Running Windows 7.
2. For the above needs I've been advised to install [Visual Studio Community 2015](https://www.visualstudio.com/).

Comment: You can have multiple versions of Visual Studio on your machine.  As long as you keep the installation directories, header file directories, etc. separate, you shouldn't have a problem.  I currently have VS 2008, VS 2013, and VS 2015 on a single machine.

Comment: If you don't change the Framework which when opening a project VS will not do this you would be fine. Now depending on the edition used for VS2010 there may be slight differences between the two yet you will have a richer IDE with VS2015.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, I have few folders starting from 2005, 2008 etc and I don't know whether it's a good or bad thing and whether I should delete them all and install a single version.

Comment: Don't delete anything.  Just install the new version in a different directory.  You have an option of specifying the installation directory name.  Everything should take care of itself from there.

Comment: This is too broad- just completely random personal experiences and upgrade advice.

Comment: @Puppy there are three lines with specific questions, in what direction should I change the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have both VS2015 and VS2010 on your machine, I currently have five different versions of VS installed.

After it's done installing, you can open your `*.sln` file(s), and VS2015 should offer to convert them to the latest version.  For C# projects, usually painless, just double-check which version of .NET framework the projects are targeting.

For C++ projects, things start getting tricky, VS2015 will convert the projects for you just dandy.  But stuff might not compile, most likely due to bugs in your code and the fact that the new C++ compiler is a lot more persnickety (a good thing).  You might also want to note which version of Windows SDK `Target Platform Version` the C++ projects are targeting, sometimes it's easier to use an older version of Windows SDK.  Likewise for CRT version `Platform Toolset`.

Answer (score 0):

I installed 2015 while keeping 2010, didn't encounter any problems.

I had one project that wouldn't compile in VS 2015 so I fired up the old version and it worked. But apart from that the new version has been better in every regard. The new Visual Studio won't break the old versions although it will prompt you to upgrade your solution files.